# Setting a column on a new row with a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table name `dblog` where the schema is like

```
data_balance_id number(8) primary key,
plan_id number(6) not null,
start_date date default current_date,
end_date date not null);
```

So I am trying to create a trigger which will update `enddate` column when a insertion is going to happen. `enddate` will be updated as 30 days from the insertion day. My trigger code is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON dblog FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dblog (end_date) values (SYSDATE()+30);
END;
/
```

The insert query is like following

```
insert into dblog (db_id, planid) values (12,123);
```

Trigger is created without any error. But at the time of insertion I am getting the following error

```
insert into dblog (db_id, planid) values (12,123)
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "E1038351.TRG1", line 2
```

Comment: You want to update, so don't insert another row: just set the value of :new.end_date

Comment: You are doing a before insert and inserting into the same table, infinite loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to modify the `:new` pseudo-record.  Something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg
  BEFORE INSERT ON dblog 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.end_date := sysdate + 30;
END;
```

If you don't want `end_date` to have a time component (or, rather, you want the time component to be midnight), you would want to `trunc(sysdate) + 30`.

Comment: It is giving error `PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.END_DATE'
`

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' - Are you certain that you used the colon prefix?  What client are you using?  It is possible that your client is trying to interpret anything with a `:` prefix as a bind variable.

Comment: Sorry There was a mistake in typing. All are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert another row, which also re-triggers the trigger.

In the triggers you have access to the row using variables `:NEW` and `:OLD`.

In case when you insert, the `:OLD` is null , because you doesn't have it in the table yet.

So before inserting row you update his columns like this:

```
:NEW.END_DATE = SYSDATE+30;
```